# Как передать данные и чтоб они хранились на время загрузки?

Tags: jquery, php

Есть различные плагины для мультизагрузки файлов на сервер. Мне как-то более всего понравился [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com). Но вот какая штука выходит. jQuery скрипт находится, допустим, в index.php, в нём указывается имя файла, который будет выполнять перемещение файла из временной папки в нужную (uploadify.php). Указать фиксированную целевую папку нельзя, так как имя папки зависит от  пользователя, который загружает файлы. Мне надо, чтоб из jQuery скрипта отправлялось название папки, в которую нужно будет поместить файл. $.get() не помогает, так как к uploadify.php происходит несколько обращений и значение сбрасывается. Через сессию тоже нельзя передать, так как пользователь не открывает uploadify.php...

Как передать данные и чтоб они хранились на время загрузки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я с этим плагином не работал плотно, но если [посмотреть документацию](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/), то можно обнаружить опцию [formData](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/) - передача дополнительных данных с каждой загрузкой файла. И кстати, [работа с сессиями](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/), там тоже предусмотрена ;)

Comment: @Deonis я там ничего не понял...
Пробовал так

onUploadStart : function() {
$.get('uploadify.php', { user: '".$_SESSION['login']."' } );
},

не передаётся гет...

Comment: Вы загружаете файл и вместе с ним передаете папку, которая относится к определенному юзверю или его данные для идентификации. Из примера в мануале:


    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'formData': {'user_login' : 'Morty', 'user_fold' : 'Morty_fold'},
        // еще какието настройки/опции
    });

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, разобрался.